# Форумы, посвященные Elementor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elementor

Пытался гуглить: https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALeKk00_a6ircRr4KbGj_6LlPXKaIsLoPg%3A1599733465581&source=hp&ei=2f5ZX9OVIJiGwPAPp9WX2A4&q=%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8B+elementor&oq=%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8B+elementor&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoICAAQsQMQgwE6BQgAELEDOgIIADoECAAQAjoICAAQFhAKEB5QwgdYqjhg_1hoAHAAeACAAZUBiAGgDZIBAzcuOZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiT5srHr97rAhUYAxAIHafqBesQ4dUDCAc&uact=5 , но не нашел хорошего форума по elementor . Подскажите (киньте ссылку).

Answer (score 0):

Официальное сообщество https://elementor.com/community/

Ветка на reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/elementor/

Поддержка плагина https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/elementor/