# Отображение сайта в WordPress и Elementor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Создал wordpress сайт digitalelectronics.ru с темой TwentyTwenty. Открывал **Внешний вид=>Настроить** и получал на экране

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем нажал **Страницы=>Все страницы=>Редактировать в Elementor** для пункта списка **Elementor #7 — Elementor** и получил на экране

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом добиться отображения в 1-м случае, такого же что и во-втором?

Comment: За каждой задачей будете сюда обращаться, возможно, стоит посмотреть [документацию WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org) и [документацию Elementor](https://developers.elementor.com)?

Comment: @IgorR. в документации все очень глубоко запрятано как https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALeKk00_a6ircRr4KbGj_6LlPXKaIsLoPg%3A1599733465581&source=hp&ei=2f5ZX9OVIJiGwPAPp9WX2A4&q=%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8B+elementor&oq=%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8B+elementor&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoICAAQsQMQgwE6BQgAELEDOgIIADoECAAQAjoICAAQFhAKEB5QwgdYqjhg_1hoAHAAeACAAZUBiAGgDZIBAzcuOZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiT5srHr97rAhUYAxAIHafqBesQ4dUDCAc&uact=5

Comment: @IgorR. на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176594/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-elementor (продолжение предыдущего комментария)

Answer (score 1):

Это разные типы данных и управление разное.

1. Это общие настройки темы - название, лого, favicon, фоны, цвета и т.д.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/appearance-customize-screen/

2. Редактирование страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял во втором случае Вы создали новую страницу с холстом elementor или же включили в записи "Привет, мир!" холст Elementor, одно из двух. (посмотрите вложение) Если вы включите Шаблон по умолчанию, то будет как вы хотите.

[image: 123]
Должно быть
[image: 1234]
Скорее всего у Вас